# Memory Management using ARC

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I have following code in my project:

```
    RBPPStockChartViewController * stocksController = [[RBPPStockChartViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RBPPStockChartViewController" bundle:nil];
    stocksController.companyCode1 = selectedCompany.companycode;
    stocksController.ticker1Text = selectedCompany.ticker;
    stocksController.isMarketIndicator = FALSE;

    if (isfromTVIndexes)
    {
        stocksController.isDJIndexesMenuDisplay = TRUE;
        stocksController.isDJIndexesDirectChartDisplay = FALSE;
    }
    stocksController.closechartdelegate = self;
    self.stockchartvc = stocksController;
    [[self view] addSubview:stocksController.view];// here retain count is incremented.
                                                   // And I am getting leak when I check               
                                                   //with instrument.
```

I am using ARC.
I want to know how to overcome this leak.

Comment: LOL I find this title to be an oxymoron.  Regardless, **ignore what retain count says**.  Everyone who has used the Internet at least once in the past 2 years and their dog should know this by now.  The retain count *should* go up by one there though (that is normal behavior).

Comment: You need to provide the evidence to support your conclusion of a leak, because I doubt it very much.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of thoughts:

1. This technique of adding a controller to some strong variable and then adding its view as a subview is not a recommended way of present another view. You really should be using

   ```
   [self presentViewController:stocksController animated:YES completion:NULL]
   ```

   or

   ```
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:stocksController animated:YES]
   ```

   (or, if you're determined to do it the way you have, you should do the view controller containment calls, such a `addChildController` and `didMoveToParentViewController`). If you let your view controller hierarchy get out of sync with your view hierarchy, you can end up not getting certain events (notably rotation events; for a lengthy discussion on the problems/risks of not doing this carefully, see [WWDC 2011 session - Implementing UIViewController Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102)). Also, if you did it properly, you wouldn't have to keep your strong reference in `self.stockchartvc` nor have a `closechartdelegate` at all (nor the code that likely calls).

   And, by the way, if you adopt one of these well-established patterns (modal/push transitions or view controller containment), that might fix the memory issue there.
2. Alternatively, if you don't fix this structural problem, then you might need to take a closer look at the code that `closechartdelegate` calls. I.e. Does it `removeFromParentView`? Does it `nil` the `stockchartvc` variable? If you don't do both of those things, you'll effectively leak.
3. You don't use any repeating timers or anything else that might result in a strong reference cycle, are you? For example, I hope `closechartdelegate` is `weak`.

If you still can't fix the problem, we probably need to see the memory semantics of `stockchartvc`, `closechartdelegate`, and see the code that the `closechartdelegate` is calling.

Comment: I love a Rob "couple of thoughts" answer, and this is no exception!